# Quando tento enviar um email utilizando aspas usando o phpmailler o email não envia,

Tags: php, phpmailer

Pessoal Gostaria da ajuda de vocês!

Configurei o phpmailler no meu projeto e funcionou tudo certinho, mas quando eu tento enviar um e-mail com aspas simples ou duplas o email não envia! como faço pra resolver sem perder o conteúdo na hora do envio do email?

```
try {
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        ));

    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';          // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('',$username);
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);     // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $titulo;
    $mail->Body =  "$corpoEmail <br><br> Status da solicitação : ".$status_solicitacao;
    $mail->AltBody = "$corpoEmail <br><br> Status da solicitação : ".$status_solicitacao;
   
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $update)) {
        insert_ocorrencia();
        $mail->send();
        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Solicitação concluida com sucesso!');window.location.href='../pages/backlog.php';</script>";
        
    }else{
        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro na conclusão da solicitação');window.location.href='../pages/backlog.php';</script>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no envio do email');window.location.href='../pages/backlog.php';</script>";
    
}
```

Comment: Cade o eu código?

Comment: acabei de editar a publicação e coloquei o codigo

Comment: Já tentou utilizar `html_decode_entity("$corpoEmail <br><br> Status da solicitação : ".$status_solicitacao");`

Comment: utilizei o html_entity_decode mas continuou apresentando erro